# Вывод из связанных моделей Django

Tags: django, foreign-key

Есть несколько связанных моделей:

```
class regSurname(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Фамилия')


class regName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Имя')
    surname_key = models.ForeignKey(regSurname, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='regsurname', verbose_name='Имя')


class regPatronymic(models.Model):
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Отчество')
    name_key = models.ForeignKey(regName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patronymic', verbose_name='Отчество')
```

Вопрос, как получить в шаблоне связанные ФИО всех записей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аннотации и функции `F`, `Value`, `Concat` из `django.db.models` вам [в помощь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Concat)

```
# views.py
qs = reSurname.objects.select_related('regsurname', 'regsurname__patronymic').annotate(full_name=Concat(F('surname'), Value(' '), F('regsurname__name'), Value(' '), F('regsurname__patronymic__patronymic')))

context = {'objects': qs}

# tempalate.html
{% for x in objects %}
    {{ x.full_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Для случаев, когда нет одной из связей, используйте `Case` и `When` из того же `django.db.models`